# CartThrob - Multiple Languages

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, localization

Does anyone know whether CartThrob supports additional languages from a front-end perspective? It would be great to know whether it is possible to localise all product and checkout content within the same add-on.

Thanks,
Adeeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Cartthrob uses regular channels and entries there is no reason it would not work with one of the multi-language add-ons such as; [Multi language support](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/multi-language-support) or [Multilanguage Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/multi-language-module)

You could even create your own system by adding some extra fields to your entries.

For example, if you have a text field for a product description named {product-description} you could create a French version called {fr-product-description}.

Then create your url structure and templates to use a language code within the urls. So the English version might be /en/products/my-product and the French version would be /fr/products/my-product.

You can then look for the first url segment and inject it into any custom field tags that you output to the template, or use conditionals to switch out the different language content.

EDIT: I'm going to have to test this now as I'm unsure whether it will work. Worth a try though if you don't want to use an add-on.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. [Transcribe](http://eeharbor.com/transcribe) looks like a great add-on which could bring all of that together nicely.